# How to reduce tensorflow-js dependency size while using danfojs-node

Tags: node.js, tensorflow.js, danfojs

[DanfoJS](https://github.com/javascriptdata/danfojs) provides two versions

- [danfojs-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/danfojs-node) (for NodeJS)
- `danfojs` ( browser side)

`DanfoJS` depends on `tensorflow-js`.

While installing `danfoJS-node` for a server side NodeJS application, we observe `tensorflow-js` dependency of `danfojs-node` takes around --> **700 MB**

Is there a way to install only parts of `tensorflow-js` that we use in the application ?

Details : danfojs-node - version - `1.1.2`